# Google Maps Markerclusterer - Manually Set Zoom Level

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers, markerclusterer

I use Google Maps Markerclusterer and normally it works great. The problem I am having is when only 1 marker is being displayed (due to users choosing options resulting in 1 marker) the clusterer is setting the zoom level all the way in to the closest level.

Is there any way I can manually set my zoom level and still use the clusterer? I found the MaxZoomLevel feature but that doesn't actually control the zoom. Trying to set the zoom manually at initiate did not work either.

Thanks!

Comment: Fitting the bounds was over-riding any zoom changes I tried to make. Easy fix when there's only 1 marker: disable the fitbounds.

    //map.fitBounds(bounds); << disabled
    map.setCenter(bounds.getCenter()); //added to center on the 1 marker
    map.setZoom(17); //set zoom

Comment: Sorry for the lack of formatting above, stackoverflow wont let me answer my own question for 6 more hours and I probably won't be back.